# Find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing specific sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $\Omega = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, my task is to find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{0\}$ and $\{0,2\}$.

Here is my attempt:

I know that a $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of sets of $\Omega$ that is closed under countable union, countable intersection, and complements. With this definition in mind and letting $A = \{\{0\}, \{0,2\} \}$, I think I have found the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of $A$, denoted $\sigma(A)$ to be
$$ \sigma(A) = \{ \emptyset, \Omega, \{0\}, \{0,2\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1,3\} \} $$

Is this correct? My thought process was to just take complements of the provided sets and then take unions of all elements generated through that process, and then finally taking the intersection of all such elements.

Comment: You are missing $\{2\}$ and $\{0,1,3\}$ at least.

Comment: Repeatedly take intersections, unions and complements until you can't create any new sets. Then you are done. You aren't done yet, as has already been pointed out.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you for pointing that out, after going through it a few times I think those were the only sets I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\Omega$ is any set and that $E_1, \ldots, E_k$ are *disjoint* subsets of $\Omega$ which form a partition (i.e. their union is $\Omega$). We want to find $\mathscr{F} = \sigma(\{E_1, \ldots, E_k\}).$ *We propose to demonstrate that $\mathscr{F} = \left\{ \bigcup\limits_{j \in F} E_j \middle| F \subset \{1, \ldots, k\} \text{ is finite}\right\}.$* As a corollary, $\mathrm{card}(\mathscr{F}) = 2^k.$

Then,

- $\mathscr{F}$ is clearly closed under countable unions;
- $\varnothing \in \mathscr{F}$ (take $F = \varnothing$);
- $A \in \mathscr{F} \implies A^\complement \in \mathscr{F}$ for if $A = \bigcup\limits_{j \in F} E_j$ then $A^\complement = \bigcup\limits_{j \in F^\complement} E_j$ (here $F^\complement$ is $\{1,\ldots,k\}\setminus F$).

Thus, the claim has been demonstrated.

In your exercise, it is rather easy to see that $\sigma(A) = \sigma(\{\{0\},\{2\},\{1,3\}\}).$ Hence, you should have $2^3 = 8$ elements.

Comment: By the way, the $E_j$ are called "atoms" of the sigma field $\mathscr{F}.$ I think the proposition generalises _mutatis mutandis_ to a countable family of $E_j.$ Unfortunately, unless you have explicitly the atoms and a countable number of them, there are no explicit descriptions of sigma algebras.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for clarifying this! I am new to measure theory and $\sigma$-algebras so it takes me a while to get it all down but this helps out more than I can say in words!